# Avoid creating almost identical case classes

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, shapeless

often running into this situation

slick generated `case` classes

```
case class Person(firstname:String,lastname:String)
case class Address(zip:String,city:String,state:String)
```

commonly front end JSON contract has `Person` along with `Address`. traditionally requiring to create a class as

```
case class PersonWithAddress(firstname:String,lastname:String,address:Address)
```

Such requirement is common across the boards.

Its bit cumbersome to create and maintain such placeholder classes. Any nifty tricks can help create such data structure on the fly which can be JSON friendly. Is there a case for using Shapeless here ? (note: JSON transformations are happening using playframework JSON lib)

Comment: For me, `PersonWithAddress` would just be `Person`, and the `Address` field would always be there. And if for some reason I don't need it all the time, then I use `Option[Address]`. It's not perfect, but it removes a lot of duplication.

Comment: @m-z : that's not true in my case. As I mentioned all my db tables and corresponding `case class`es are generated using slick code generator. even if they are handwritten still they are strictly Table objects and has to comply to db table definition

Comment: wat. Why do you think case classes have to map directly to database tables?

Comment: It is useful for build-time checking of db schema changes. E.g. the schema was changed, the case class mapping is generated during build, then correctness is statically checked during compilation of dependent projects. Do you know a better way for avoiding runtime errors on breaking schema changes?

Comment: Are you using play macro inceptions?

Comment: @rightføld :as mentioned in the question we use slick and note slick code generator which generates mapping slick Table, TableQuery and Case classes (mapping with tables). if you have looked at slick, that's the pattern it follows. Creating/manipulating slick mapping classes doesn't sound practical.

Comment: @ponythewhite : yes. play macro for serialize /deserialize request/response

Comment: @VikasPandya I have used Slick and creating mappings manually was very practical. In fact, a bad design is impractical.

Comment: It is possible to use HLists for json validation, to map request to hlist, after that it is possible to make from hlist classes you want (http://mandubian.com/2014/01/31/play-rules-shapeless/); but not sure it is more beatiful rather then creating a case class for binding request.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your JSON case class as `case class PersonWithAddress(person: Person, address:Address)` but then you'd need to write a custom serializer if you wanted to flatten the first name and last name (instead of leaving them nested inside a sub document).

That's probably more code than simply repeating a case class, but at least you'd get some compile-time checking if the underlying case classes were to change (which you don't have with copy/pasted case classes).